# How can I make link to windows unlock my phone?

Tags: windows, samsung-galaxy-s-23

As the title says, I want to be able to use Phone Link from my windows 10 pro laptop and screen my phone without having to unlock the phone, as this defeats the purpose. I already used adb to give link to windows access to always screen my phone so I dont have to get up to go to my phone to press allow recording. Im using a samsung s23u, running android 14, oneui6

Comment: Not possible (asked and answered already by Microsoft themselves): https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/connect-to-phone-from-pc-without-having-to-use-the/1d758b61-bbd3-4a95-a8db-77527375a477